# Array struct sort - C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I want to sort an strut-array and I keep getting an certain issue and I don't know why

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define STRLEN 20

 void BubbleSort(int a[], int array_size);

struct schueler
{
    char vorname[STRLEN];
    char nachname[STRLEN];
    char klasse[6];
    char gbdatum[9];
    double geld;
};

int main()
{
    int anz;
    int count = 1;
    printf("Wieviele Schueler moechten Sie eingaben: ");
    scanf("%d",&anz);
    struct schueler personen[anz];
    while(count <= anz)
    {
        printf("\n\nSchueler %d:\n\n", count);

        printf("\nNachname: ");
        scanf("%s",&personen[count].nachname);

        printf("\nVorname: ");
        scanf("%s",&personen[count].vorname);

        printf("\nKlasse: ");
        scanf("%s",&personen[count].klasse);

        printf("\nGeburtsdatum");
        scanf("%s",&personen[count].gbdatum);

        printf("\nGeld: ");
        scanf("%d",&personen[count].geld);

        count++;
    }
    BubbleSort(&personen, anz);
    system("CLS");
    for(count = 1; count <= anz; count++)
    {
        printf("Schueler %d:\n\n", count);
        printf("Nachname: ", personen[count].nachname);
        printf("Vorname: ", personen[count].vorname);
        printf("Klasse: ", personen[count].klasse);
        printf("Geburtsdatum: ", personen[count].gbdatum);
        printf("Geld: ", personen[count].geld);
    }
}

 void BubbleSort(int a[], int array_size)
 {
     int i, j, temp;
     for (i = 0; i < (array_size - 1); ++i)
     {
          for (j = 0; j < array_size - 1 - i; ++j )
          {
               if (a[j].nachname > a[j+1].nachname)
               {
                    temp = a[j+1].nachname;
                    a[j+1].nachname = a[j].nachname;
                    a[j].nachname = temp;
               }
          }
     }
 }
```

The issue is

> error: request for member 'nachname' in something not a structure or union

Comment: @SirPing  The first parameter of the function  void BubbleSort(int a[], int array_size); is invalid. It must be of the type struct schueler[]

Comment: what did the compiler say?

Comment: Until your program compiles warning free (using -Wall with gcc for example) we cannot help you.

Comment: Use `qsort` for sort.

Comment: Shouldn't the line `struct schueler personen[anz];` be `schueler personen[anz];` instead?

Comment: There are many coding errors in your BubbleSort function. As others said, the first parameter should be of type struct shueler [], the second error is when you compare two arrays of characters if (a[j].nachname > a[j+].nachname), the alphabetic comparaison is not done you must use character by character comparaison. The third error is when you assign to a int type (temp), an array of characters. Define temp as an array of char then use deep copy functions like strcpy

Comment: @Travis The struct is not `typedef`ed. You have to use the struct prefix because they live in a different namespace in c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> error: request for member 'nachname' in something not a structure or union
> ```

```
    if (a[j].nachname > ...
```

`a` is a pointer to `int` *not* to `struct schueler`, so what it points to does *not* have a member `nachname`.

To fix this change

```
void BubbleSort(int a[], int array_size)
```

to be

```
void BubbleSort(struct schueler a[], int array_size)
```

And call it like this

```
BubbleSort(personen, anz); /* note, that the & had been removed. */
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort an array, use `qsort`. I am not quite clear on the `>` operation that was used to compare the strings (`a[j].nachname > a[j+1].nachname`) but that is a side issue